# Is it possible to call the original delegate from a delegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, delegates

Out of curiosity, is it possible to call the original delegate method implementation in a custom delegate implementation. like [super delegateMethod]; Or is that not possible. There are some scenarios where'd id like to add customizations to the behavior if certain conditions are met. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved via a wrapper object which intercepts messages and forwards them to another delegate object.  The following class intercepts calls to the scrollViewDidScroll: method before forwarding it (and any other delegate method invocations) to another UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
@import UIKit;

@interface ScrollHandler : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate>
- (instancetype)initWithScrollViewDelegate:(id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)delegate;
@end

@implementation ScrollHandler {
    id<UIScrollViewDelegate> _scrollViewDelegate;
}

- (instancetype)initWithScrollViewDelegate:(id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _scrollViewDelegate = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}

// Intercept specific method invocations:

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Implement custom behavior here before forwarding the invocation to _scrollViewDelegate
    [_scrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}

// Forward unintercepted method invocations:

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    // Ask _scrollViewDelegate if it responds to the selector (and ourself as well)
    return [_scrollViewDelegate respondsToSelector:selector] || [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    // Forward the invocation to _scrollViewDelegate
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:_scrollViewDelegate];
}

@end
```

Example use:

```
_scrollView = [[ScrollHandler alloc] init];
_scrollController = [[ScrollHandler alloc] initWithScrollViewDelegate:self];
_scrollView.delegate = _scrollController;
```

Comment: Oh how interesting! I wouldn't have thought to wrap the class in another class, but that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!